# JVM can't find class when using JNI from C++

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call JAVA methods from C++ by JNI. First of all, I got [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/993067/Calling-Java-from-Cplusplus-with-JNI) example, tried it out. I changed the path of JDK and after that I could run the examples and they properly worked.

After that, I tried to import my own JAR file and use one class from it. I copied the code from the example and replaced the classpath and classname with my own:

```
void MyCPPClass::CallJava()
{
    JavaVM *jvm;                // Pointer to the JVM (Java Virtual Machine)
    JNIEnv *env;                // Pointer to native interface

    //==================== prepare loading of Java VM ============================

    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;                        // Initialization arguments
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[ 1 ];   // JVM invocation options
    options[ 0 ].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=MyJar.jar";   // where to find java .class
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;             // minimum Java version
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;                          // number of options
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;     // invalid options make the JVM init fail

    //================= load and initialize Java VM and JNI interface ===============

    jint rc = JNI_CreateJavaVM( &jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args );  // YES !!
    delete options;    // we then no longer need the initialisation options. 

    //========================= analyse errors if any  ==============================
    // if process interuped before error is returned, it's because jvm.dll can't be 
    // found, i.e.  its directory is not in the PATH. 

    if( rc != JNI_OK )
    {
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }    

    jclass cls1 = env->FindClass( "aaa/bbb/MyClass" );
    ...
}
```

The JAR contains only one class `aaa.bbb.MyClass` and it's made with IntelliJ IDEA and `mvn package` command. I copied the JAR file next to my executable.

A value of `rc` is always 0 (`JNI_OK`), but the value of `cls1` is always `NULL`. I think that JVM can find the JAR, because when I'm debugging I can't delete the JAR after `FindClass`.

The JAR file contains the MyClass.class file, I checked it.

I have checked some previous questions ( [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40911447/load-jar-file-in-c-using-jni), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989206/how-to-load-jar-file-in-c-using-jni), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025397/can-c-application-load-the-jar-file-using-jni) and some others) yet, but I couldn't get where I made a mistake.

**UPDATE:** I tried to copy the MyClass.class file and MyJar.jar file into the directory of the example linked before, and JVM can't find `MyClass`. It's possible that something missing from my java source file? The package declaration is correct.

What can cause that JVM can't find `MyClass`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> **SOLUTION:** I had to add the maven dependencies' JARs to the classpath. Now it works!